# Why is bulkCreate only writing a limited number of records in DB (Postgres && Sequelize)

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am using Postgres and Sequelize to create a file that when called, creates an array of objects, which has **3034 separate items** within it. I then pass this array to my model 'SignalDegs' with the call **bulkCreate**. As I watch node execute the file, from what it looks like all the items are being read within the function, the last line output is a console.log that I've written to confirm that an error was not caught.

After double-checking with my Postgres DB by selecting all records, I see that only the first **185 rows** are written.

Is there a limit to how many records can be written with bulkCreate?

Function Call

```
  SignalDefs.bulkCreate(signalArray, { ignoreDuplicates: true })
    .then(() => {
      console.log('created signal defs records successfully');
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(`Error returned from bulk insert: ${err}`);
    });
```

Model:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const db = require('../database/index.js');

const SignalDefs = db.define(
  'signaldefs',
  {
    signalID: { autoIncrement: true, type: Sequelize.INTEGER },
    signalType: { primaryKey: true, type: Sequelize.STRING },
    messageSource: { primaryKey: true, type: Sequelize.STRING },
    messageName: { primaryKey: true, type: Sequelize.STRING },
    signalName: { primaryKey: true, type: Sequelize.STRING },
    unit: { primaryKey: true, type: Sequelize.STRING }
  },
  { freezeTableName: true }
);

const FloatSignals = db.define(
  'floatsignals',
  {
    signalID: { primaryKey: true, type: Sequelize.INTEGER },
    vehicleID: { primaryKey: true, type: Sequelize.INTEGER },
    floatValue: { type: Sequelize.FLOAT },
    time: { primaryKey: true, type: Sequelize.DATE }
  },
  { freezeTableName: true }
);

module.exports = { SignalDefs, FloatSignals };
```

The subset: of signalArray being inserted

```
[ { signalType: '4',
    messageSource: 'TPUINPUT',
    messageName: 'TPUINPUT_status',
    signalName: 'powerStatus',
    unit: '',
    createdAt: 2020-02-12T13:52:25.747Z,
    updatedAt: 2020-02-12T13:52:25.747Z },
  { signalType: '4',
    messageSource: 'GTW',
    messageName: 'TPUMCU_status',
    signalName: 'regenStatus',
    unit: '',
    createdAt: 2020-02-12T13:52:25.747Z,
    updatedAt: 2020-02-12T13:52:25.747Z },
  { signalType: '4',
    messageSource: 'GTW',
    messageName: 'TPUMCU_status',
    signalName: 'powerStatus',
    unit: '',
    createdAt: 2020-02-12T13:52:25.747Z,
    updatedAt: 2020-02-12T13:52:25.747Z },
  { signalType: '4',
    messageSource: 'GTW',
    messageName: 'TPUMCU_status',
    signalName: 'driveStatus',
    unit: '',
    createdAt: 2020-02-12T13:52:25.747Z,
    updatedAt: 2020-02-12T13:52:25.747Z },
  { signalType: '4',
    messageSource: 'TPUINPUT',
    messageName: 'TPUINPUT_kill',
    signalName: 'killRequest',
    unit: '',
    createdAt: 2020-02-12T13:52:25.747Z,
    updatedAt: 2020-02-12T13:52:25.747Z }]
```

Comment: Are you should you don't try to insert 2849 duplicates among other items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sequelize but the database itself has specific restriction on how many records you can insert at a time.
For MS SQL there is a limit of 1000 records at a time. See the reference below
https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-insert-multiple-rows/

Check documentation for Postgres DB there should be certain limit to it.